# How to find the best fit point inside a cluster?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, clustering, centroid

I have a `cluster` with many points.

Like this:

[image]

Where I can visually identify a `cluster` of points and a `noise point`.

[image]

**Question:** I would like to know how can I find the best fit point via an algorithm/math formulas. Not the centroid of the cluster, but the best fit point... probably the closest point to the cluster centroid without taking into account the noise point(s).

[image]

Comment: PAM algorithm is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks @nicomezi Can you put that on the answer so I can close this question?:)

Answer (score 0):

The PAM algorithm (for partition around medoïd) is an algorithm close to the usual k-means which allows to works with data points as cluster centers.